# How does underlying functionality for email forwarding work?

Tags: email

I noticed specific behaviors when forward in emails and wanted to know where the code resides for this...  If I forward an email in Gmail for example, it has a section with all the previous threads hidden by ellipsis (...) or "show quoted text" that contains the all the previous thread.  All the text is purple/faded.

Now.. I can edit this forwarded purple text. However this changes what you see by default. Now the edited portion will appear verbatim outside the ellipsis, and in black, but the unedited portion is still contained in the "show quoted text" portion.

Lastly, if I make an edit far Midway down in a longer thread-chain, it appears as if the entire fwd thread text appears outside the ellipsis, but only the edited text appears in black whereas the rest of the text is still faded and purple.

I am not necessarily looking for exact answers, this is only using Gmail.  I just want to know where I can look to see examples of this code in action, or where this code lies in the layers of functionality of email. Or better, play with this type of code.

Sorry, didn't know where else to go, just REALLY curious about this one.

Answer (score 1):

A forwarded email is either forwarded inline (the text is just copied into the body of the new email) or as an attachment. MIME attachments are described in various RFCs, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME is probably an easier place to start.

As for Gmail's color coding: it just parses the email bodies and applies colors to indicate levels of comments. Per usenet etiquette, quoted email lines are prefixed with `>`, and that's what Gmail uses as indicator. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-posting

Comment: Thank you this gives me a great start, I didn't even have good starting search terms!